# Can we create TABLE datatype in Sybase?

Tags: sap-ase

As we have in SQL Server, is it possible to create a TABLE datatype in Sybase? I checked a couple of online forums but was not able to find any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TABLE is a T-SQL reserved word, so is not usable as the name of a datatype.

The full list of reserved words can be found in the [Sybase ASE Quick Reference Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc70202.1550/html/quickref/X10189.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the input. Is there any other way to create a data type that has a collection of columns in sybase?

Comment: Not that I am aware of in ASE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question recently. The table data type does exist in T-SQL as illustrated by MSDN library https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx. HOWEVER, It is NOT SUPPPORTED in Sybase. In T-SQL the table data type can be declared AS

```
DECLARE @tableVariable table(Column1 int, Column2 int)
```

I had intended on using the table variable to store a result set for use later to be UNION'd for each value in an array, but I was disappointed to find out that Sybase ASE DOES NOT support the table data type variable. A list of supported data types can be found [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278452897615.html)

Answer (score 0):

To create a temporary table in Sybase you will use the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Column1 int, Column2 int)
```

Example of select:

```
SELECT * FROM #table
```

The table exists until the current session or procedure ends, or until its owner drops it using drop table.